# Foundation 5 responsive sub menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I am using the Foundation 5 framework for a WordPress website and need to improve the responsive menu. My menu will have a lot of drop down items which as it stands at the moment will all sit on top of each other when viewed on a smaller screen. I need some sort of accordion effect with a plus button to drop down each item. If this is possible with the Foundation menu can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is a screenshot which shows what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let´s try this one (you need to play with the rules position and font size):

note: Without code is a shoot in the dark :)

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
    content: "+";
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```